# Silverfish in a restaurant

Tags: food-safety

If I'm eating at a restaurant and a silverfish scuttles across the table top, what should I reasonably conclude? Should I be concerned about the food hygiene?

Comment: The one time this happened to me I finished eating my pizza, but I never ate there again. Not that was likely anyways, I was only in that dive because that were my friends wanted to go.

Comment: take a detailed look at the menu. If it happens to be silverfish there, return it to the kitchen

Comment: Silverfish eat paper and dry rotted wood. It probably means the building needs repair.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise eating there again. Silverfish or harmless to humans, but their presence can signify some serious hygiene issues. While silverfish are most known to feeding on decaying wood, in a kitchen setting, they are signs of 1) poor moisture control, which can include leaks and spills that are left unmopped, and 2) the presence of uncleansed floors, corners, and prep areas. Silverfish are particularly fond of starches and food debris. You can find a quick summary of silverfish in a food prep setting at [Cannon Hygiene](http://www.cannonhygiene.ie/Documents/Pest%20of%20the%20month%20-%20Silverfish.pdf).